# Can't use multiple instances of same parallax code in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, scroll, parallax

I can't seem to use multiple copies of a set piece of code I'm using to make a parallax effect. It will only count the most recent one and nothing before. Here's the code used twice:

```
$(window).scroll(function (e) {
    parallax();
});

function parallax() {
    var scrolled = $(window).scrollTop();
    $('.bg').css('top', -(scrolled * 0.1) + 'px');
};
$(window).scroll(function (e) {
    parallax();
});

function parallax() {
    var scrolled = $(window).scrollTop();
    $('.bg2').css('top', -(scrolled * 0.2) + 'px');
};
```

And an example on JSFiddle of the code in action: (http://jsfiddle.net/9k9ucm49/)

Any ideas on what to do here? Sorry if the fix is obvious, I'm a relatively new user when it comes to Javascript.

Comment: Well I'm pretty sure that in a normal OO language, overloading a function will will have you use the most local version of that function. That's how you can re-write some predefined functions for your own purposes. Javascript however doesn't really support this type of overloading, not the way you'd like. I'd look up a different way to achieve the effect you're looking for.

Comment: You have 2 functions with the same name that do different things (`* 0.1` vs `* 0.2`). What do you expect to happen?

Comment: Welp, changing the name did the trick. I'm going to go shy away and bang my head against the wall now. :D